# How can I choose a particular line of a DataFrame after `groupBy()`?

Tags: pyspark

I have a pyspark DataFrame: `df`. For example:

```
 e | attempt | grade
---------------------
 1 | 1       | 100
 2 | 1       | 95
 2 | 2       | 55
 3 | 1       | 78
 3 | 2       | 100
 3 | 3       | 88
.
.
.
```

I want to choose for each value of "e" only a single line:
the line that has the maximal "attempt" value of all the other lines with the same value of "e" and that their attempt is less than X.

For example, if I call `get_results(3)` I should get the following:

```
 e | attempt | grade
---------------------
 1 | 1       | 100
 2 | 2       | 55
 3 | 3       | 88
.
.
.
```

If I call `get_results(2)` I should get the following:

```
 e | attempt | grade
---------------------
 1 | 1       | 100
 2 | 2       | 55
 3 | 2       | 100
.
.
.
```

If I call `get_results(1)` I should get the following:

```
 e | attempt | grade
---------------------
 1 | 1       | 100
 2 | 1       | 95
 3 | 1       | 78
.
.
.
```

I figured I should start with `df.groupby('e')`, but I can't figure out how to continue from there.

Comment: What is `X` here?

Comment: @cph_sto This is the input of `get_results(X)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to first order the DataFrame with column `e` and with `attempt` (in descending) order. Once that is done, we select the top row.

```
# Loading the requisite packages and creating the DataFrame.
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, first, row_number

valuesCol = [(1,1,100),(2,1,95),(2,2,55),(3,1,78),(3,2,100),(3,3,88)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(valuesCol,['e','attempt','grade'])
df.show()
+---+-------+-----+
|  e|attempt|grade|
+---+-------+-----+
|  1|      1|  100|
|  2|      1|   95|
|  2|      2|   55|
|  3|      1|   78|
|  3|      2|  100|
|  3|      3|   88|
+---+-------+-----+
```

Now, we select a value of `X`. As OP says, the value of `attempt` must not be greater than `X`, so we filter out all those rows where `attempt` is greater than `X` and then order using [`orderBy()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.orderBy) function.

```
X=2
w = Window.partitionBy(col('e')).orderBy(col('attempt').desc())    
df = df.where(col('attempt')<=X).orderBy(['e','attempt'], ascending=[1,0])
df.show()
+---+-------+-----+
|  e|attempt|grade|
+---+-------+-----+
|  1|      1|  100|
|  2|      2|   55|
|  2|      1|   95|
|  3|      2|  100|
|  3|      1|   78|
+---+-------+-----+
```

Once that is done, we use [`row_number()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.row_number) and [`window`](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html) function to select the top row in this sorted DataFrame.

```
df = df.withColumn('row_num', row_number().over(w)).where(col('row_num') == 1).drop('row_num')
df.show()
+---+-------+-----+
|  e|attempt|grade|
+---+-------+-----+
|  1|      1|  100|
|  3|      2|  100|
|  2|      2|   55|
+---+-------+-----+
```